# Keyboard input works,but changing a value of an input does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i've been trying to write a script that will bet on a gambling site(gamdom) based on strategies of users. On site,there is an input with bet size number and a button to bet.

I have tried to change input value with .val(),attr(),also adding .trigger() and other stuff i googled,but when you click on the button to bet it gets value that was written by a user with keyboard before anyway. I dont really understand why and i would really appreciate your help.

```
//leave page active
Object.defineProperty(document, "hidden", { value : false});
//Arrive js from github(didnt include here becouse it's large);


function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
}   

//fakeClick from StackOverflow
function fakeClick(event, anchorObj) {
  if (anchorObj.click) {
    anchorObj.click()
  } else if(document.createEvent) {
    if(event.target !== anchorObj) {
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
      evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 
      var allowDefault = anchorObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
      // you can check allowDefault for false to see if
      // any handler called evt.preventDefault().
      // Firefox will *not* redirect to anchorObj.href
      // for you. However every other browser will.
    }
  }
}

(() => {
    let startingsum = 500;
    let bettingsum = startingsum;
    let betdistance;

    function StartBetting(){
        betdistance = randomInteger(10,25);
        //if a roll passed
        $(document).arrive(".recentBustsContainer a", function() {
            betdistance--;
            //bet
            if(betdistance == 0)
            {
                //value is changing,but bet value does not
                $('.bet-input-div .form-control').attr('value', '100');
                //$('.bet-input-div .form-control').val('100');
                fakeClick(event, document.getElementsByClassName('bet-button')[8]);
            }
            //check if you win
            else if(betdistance == -1)
            {
                let str = $(this).text();
                let mult = parseFloat(str.substring(0, str.length - 1));
                //...
            }
        });
    }
    StartBetting();

})();
```

Comment: You need to post your code for us to check whats going on on there.

Comment: site is not mine,i am just trying to change value on site,based on a selector 
//my code
$('.bet-input-div .form-control').attr('value', '50');
//input code
http://prntscr.com/ihmyiz

Comment: posted code,hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.bet-input-div .form-control').value = 'abc';
```

Assuming that your selector is right

Comment: selector is right,double checked it. Didn't work sadly.

Comment: @АлександрГридин try to modify value of search input in google.com, is that work?
May be your betting site have some js function to prevent modifying input field by js

Comment: yeah,it works fine with other inputs,and i imagine the site indeed has change prevention. Maybe someone knows the way to get around it. I tried simulating typing with some guy's github library but it didnt work.